# Test a Textarea for All Keywords in an Array

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

I found a variation on this code elsewhere in StackOverflow. It takes all words from a textarea and converts them into a regular expression. It then tests an array to see if all the words in the regex are contained in the array:

```
<textarea id="inputtext" type="text"></textarea>
<input id="searchbutton" type="button" value="Click me" />

var links = new Array("taxi","Alpha","runway");


$("#searchbutton").click(function () {
    var query = $("#inputtext").val();
    var querywords = query.split(',');

    for (var i = 0; i < querywords.length; i++) {
        var regex = new RegExp('(?=.*\\b' + querywords[i].split(' ').join('\\b)(?=.*\\b')    + '\\b)', 'i', 'g');
        for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
            if (regex.test(links[j])) {                      
                console.log("Correct");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How can I reverse the process so the program returns "true" if the textarea words includes all of the keywords within the array? For example, if the textarea had the sentence "Taxi to the runway via taxiway alpha," and the array named "links" contained the keywords "taxi" "alpha" and "runway", the program would return "true".

Comment: You know that you declared an array with one item?

Comment: Loop through the array and try matching for the words in the textbox.

Comment: Can `taxi` match `taxiway`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods provided by other answers are simple, but they could be more efficient.
It's almost always better to use an object as a map to speed up lookups instead of having to search the entiry array everytime.

```
var words = ['word1', 'word2'],
    wordsMap = 'text area content, word1 and word2'.split(/\W+/).reduce(function (obj, word) {
        obj[word] = true;
        return obj;
    }, {}),
    areWordsAllContained = words.every(function (word) {
        return wordsMap[word.toLowerCase()];
    });

console.log(areWordsAllContained); //true
```

EDIT: I've changed the splitting regex from `\s+` to `\W+` to make sure that it splits on every non-word characters.

Comment: Works perfectly when input into textarea is all lowercase. How can I adjust this so any capitalization in the textarea is changed to lowercase?

Comment: Okay. I figured it out. I added toLowerCase() after textArea variable. All set! Thank you, plalx, and everyone else who contributed.

Answer (score 3):

That script you have seems to check if *any* of the words appears somewhere in the array. What you want is the [`every` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
var text = "Taxi to the runway via taxiway alpha",
    links = ["taxi", "alpha", "runway"];

console.log( links.every(function(word) {
    return new RegExp("\\b"+word+"\\b", "i").test(text);
}) ); // true
```

Comment: What does the browser support look like for the `every()` function of the Array object?

Comment: As usual, not supported in older IEs; but it can be shimmed without trouble. See the "Compatibility" section of the MDN page I linked.

Comment: Cool. Something to add to my common extensions library.

Comment: +1 for `every`, I did not even know that existed. I stole it for my answer, hope you do not mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex way would be:

```
var arr = ['word1', 'word2'], haystack = textArea.value.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
var result = true, i = 0;
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(haystack.indexOf(arr[i].toLowerCase()) === -1) {
        result = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but notice this will differ quite from regex word boundaries (e.g. on the trailing comma in OPs sentence)

Comment: @Bergi, True, but it's just a matter of using `\W+` instead.